# How to store data with view state from dynamic text box in C#?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-programming, viewstate

I am a newbie to .net. I want to insert a data in database from text box which I had created dynamically.

How can I grab data from text box to insert in database table? Following is my code.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GenerateTable(FillData());
        }
    }
    private DataTable FillData()
    {

        string query = "select en_no from student_master";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TECHNOLP-PC;Initial Catalog=SIS_Temp;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return dt;
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public void GenerateTable(DataTable dtSource)
    {
        int rowsCount = dtSource.Rows.Count;
        int colsCount = dtSource.Columns.Count;

        
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++)
        {

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colsCount; colIndex++)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();

                lbl.ID = dtSource.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString();
                lbl.Text = dtSource.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString() + "<br/>";
                tb.ID = dtSource.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString();
                tb.Text = "";
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(tb);
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wheres you code to insert the data? Ideally you write the code that saves your data, then pass in in your values from the textbox under a button click i.e.:

```
private void SaveData(NameOfObject myObject)
{
  // Save data code
  NameofObject.PropertyName = textbox.text
}
```

So here you could pass in your class object (in this case NameOfObject) then use the property and assign the textbox text property to it and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic Controls you will have to access them differently to those on the page and in ViewState.

So, on Page_Init, bind the data as normal on first load - so check for !IsPostBack.

Then, on Page_Load you should be able to get the Dynamic Controls and their values when on a PostBack. Use FindControl to get the named Controls that were dynamically created on the page.

A basic example to demonstrate...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack){
        GenerateTable(FillData());
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (var item in PlaceHolder1.Controls.Items)
        {
            TextBox txt = item.FindControl(textboxId) as TextBox;
            // And so on for the dynamic items 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it also requires a some assembly reference...
Will you please tell me missing assembly name?
And Thanx for your answer

Comment: Hi jeki, what assembly references are missing? GenerateTable(FillData()) is from your own code. PlaceHolder1.Controls is from your code too. I can't tell what is missing from this. Could you show the full code and where it is placed i.e. a web page, control etc. and which part is stating that a reference is required.

Comment: will you pelase give me your email id? so we can further communicate & i can also send my code too.